# ¿Cómo calcular el máximo para columnas secuenciales en dplyr de R?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
set.seed(2023)
df<-data.frame(id=1:20,
               x1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               x2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               y1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               y2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               p1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               p2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               t1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               t2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               w1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               w2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               z1=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T),
               z2=sample(c(1:5,NA),20,T))
df
   id x1 x2 y1 y2 p1 p2 t1 t2 w1 w2 z1 z2
1   1  5 NA  3  4  2  3  1  3  3 NA  2 NA
2   2  1  2  4  3  5  2  5  1  5  5  5  4
3   3  3 NA NA  1  5  3  4  4  1  5  1 NA
4   4  2 NA  1  1  3  3  4  5  4  3  1  2
5   5  4  5  5  3  3  4 NA  1  5  1  5  1
6   6  2  1 NA NA  3  1  1  4  3  1  2  4
7   7  1  2  2  3  1  5  2 NA  1  3  3  4
8   8  1 NA  4  4 NA  1 NA  5  2  5  5  2
9   9  5 NA  4 NA  2  5  2  2  2  1  3 NA
```

Deseo calcular el máximo por cada par de columnas, el máximo de la columna `x1` y `x2`, el máximo de `y1` y `y2`, y así hasta el `z1` y `z2`.

Lo he hecho con un `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
nombres<-names(df)[2:13]

for (i in seq(1,length(nombres),2)) {
  df[,paste0(nombres[i],"_f")]<-apply(df[,c(nombres[i],nombres[i+1])], 1, function(x){
    max(x, na.rm = T)
  })
}
```

El resultado es el esperado:

```
df
   id x1 x2 y1 y2 p1 p2 t1 t2 w1 w2 z1 z2 x1_f y1_f p1_f t1_f w1_f z1_f
1   1  5 NA  3  4  2  3  1  3  3 NA  2 NA    5    4    3    3    3    2
2   2  1  2  4  3  5  2  5  1  5  5  5  4    2    4    5    5    5    5
3   3  3 NA NA  1  5  3  4  4  1  5  1 NA    3    1    5    4    5    1
4   4  2 NA  1  1  3  3  4  5  4  3  1  2    2    1    3    5    4    2
5   5  4  5  5  3  3  4 NA  1  5  1  5  1    5    5    4    1    5    5
6   6  2  1 NA NA  3  1  1  4  3  1  2  4    2 -Inf    3    4    3    4
7   7  1  2  2  3  1  5  2 NA  1  3  3  4    2    3    5    2    3    4
8   8  1 NA  4  4 NA  1 NA  5  2  5  5  2    1    4    1    5    5    5
9   9  5 NA  4 NA  2  5  2  2  2  1  3 NA    5    4    5    2    2    3
```

Pero me parece una sintaxis muy larga y engorrosa.

Mi duda se genera, entonces, como puedo realizar el mismo cálculo pero en `dplyr`. No se me ocurre como se podría hacer. ¿Hay alguna forma?
O en todo caso, ¿podría hacer más eficiente (en tiempo de ejecución) el código en R base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el lado `dplyr` te puedo sugerir algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  separate(name, sep=1, into=c("var", "num")) %>% 
  group_by(id, var) %>% 
  summarise(max=max(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups="drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = var, values_from=max) %>% 
  select(id, x, y, p, t, w, z)

# A tibble: 20 x 7
      id     x     y     p     t     w     z
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     5     4     3     3     3     2
 2     2     2     4     5     5     5     5
 3     3     3     1     5     4     5     1
 4     4     2     1     3     5     4     2
 5     5     5     5     4     1     5     5
 6     6     2  -Inf     3     4     3     4
 7     7     2     3     5     2     3     4
 8     8     1     4     1     5     5     5
 9     9     5     4     5     2     2     3
10    10     1     2     4     5     4     3
11    11     5     5     1     5     4     4
12    12     5     2     4     5     5  -Inf
13    13     5     3     5     5     4     5
14    14     2     5     4     4     4     4
15    15     3     4     4     3     3     2
16    16     5     4     2     5     4     4
17    17     4     5     2     5     4     2
18    18     5     2     1     5     3     5
19    19     2     4     4     2     5     5
20    20     2     4     4     2     5     2
```

Comentarios:

- Básicamente lo que se hace es expandir cada celda en una nueva fila
- Por la letra del nombre de columna y el id agrupamos y obtenemos el máximo
- Luego simplemente hay que transformar en un formato ancho y ordenar las columnas
- Dudo que se más performante que tu solución con R base

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Comprobaré cuál de las dos es de ejecución más rápida.